# Sorting values of a dataframe list via lookup on another table

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two dataframes The first is a key with a list of ids. The second dataframe is a table containing values for each of the ids. I'd like to sort the list of ids in the first table with values from the second DF.

For example here is DF 1:

```
1, list(rabbit,dog,cat,giraffe)
2, list(kangaroo,rhino,bear)
3, list(fish,dolphin,bird,whale)
```

and here is DF 2:

```
cat,1
dog,2
rabbit, 3
giraffe, 4
rhino, 5
kangaro, 6, 
bear, 7
bird, 8
fish, 9
dolphin, 10
whale, 11
```

after sorting I'd like the output to be like this:

```
1, list(cat,dog,rabbit,giraffe)
2, list(rhino,kangaroo,bear)
3, list(bird,fish,dolphin,whale)
```

how can I achieve this desired sort in spark/scala?

I have tried `.sort()` but that just orders the values alphabetically

Comment: What is the expected size of the second RDD? Can we assume that it is small enough to be broadcasted?

Comment: no you can not assume that

Comment: Rdd or dataframe?

Comment: Rough idea: explode, join, groupBy, sort?

Comment: Very rough indeed

Comment: its a dataframe. I will update the question

Comment: is there a way to pass a function into orderBy()?

Comment: Indeed explode and join etc.

Comment: Not sure of performance whilst podcasting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: You can explode the list, join it to the sorting DF to have the order column, and then use windowing to collect the list back in order:

Assuming DF1 is `(id: Int, list: Seq[String])` and DF2 is `(name: String, ord: Int)`:

```
val w = Window.partitionBy('id).orderBy('ord)
df1.select('id, explode('list).as("name"))
   .join(df2, "name")
   .withColumn("list", collect_list('name).over(w))
   .groupBy('id).agg(max('list))

+---+----------------------------+
|id |max(list)                   |
+---+----------------------------+
|1  |[cat, dog, rabbit, giraffe] |
|3  |[bird, fish, dolphin, whale]|
|2  |[rhino, kangaroo, bear]     |
+---+----------------------------+
```

Verified it on the small dataset you provided. Might be fairly slow if collected list is large

Comment: Brilliant thanks. I didn’t think collect_list was guaranteed to preserve order? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list.html

Comment: Good catch on the guaranteed order, updated my answer